# why the data display two times in list while adding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to make simple demo in which I added item in database but I am facing one issue.When I am adding data it show multiple time in view .
Follow the given steps

1. Click bottom right button.It show pop up screen .Write text on input field .Then press add button.It added in database.and show the text in list .It is fine.but if you add again it show the previous text as well as current text .Mean it show duplicate item  .But it is not present on database.
2. In other words .Press bottom button .Enter "A" in that it show "A" row.Secondly add "B" text .It show "A","A","B".But"A" and "B" present on  database.Why "A"  display more ?

here is my code 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVPgoP

```
app.controller('cntr',function($scope,$ionicPopup,sqlservice){


    console.log("main controller");
        sqlservice.setup();
       // sqlservice.deleteTable();
        $scope.input={};
        $scope.items=[];
        $scope.itemToEdit = 0;
        $scope.iseditDone=false;
       $scope.loadTask = function() {
        sqlservice.getAllCases().then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            $scope.items.push(data[i]);
          console.log($scope.items);
        })
       }
       $scope.loadTask();
        $scope.showPopup = function() {
            $scope.item = {}

            // An elaborate, custom popup
            var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                template: '<input type="text" ng-model="item.CaseName" style="border: 1px solid red" autofocus>',
                title: 'Enter Add Test case',
                subTitle: 'Add Test case name',
                scope: $scope,
                buttons: [
                    { text: 'Cancel' },
                    {
                        text: '<b>Add</b>',
                        type: 'button-positive',
                        onTap: function(e) {
                            if (!$scope.item.CaseName) {
                                //don't allow the user to close unless he enters wifi password
                                e.preventDefault();
                            } else {
                                return $scope.item;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ]
            });
            myPopup.then(function(res) {
                console.log('Tapped!', res);

                if(typeof res!='undefined' && !$scope.iseditDone) {

                   // $scope.items.push(res);
                  console.log($scope.items)
                    sqlservice.insertData(res.CaseName);
                   $scope.loadTask();
                }else if(typeof res!='undefined' && $scope.iseditDone){

                    $scope.iseditDone = false;
                   // $scope.items[$scope.itemToEdit] = res;
                  sqlservice.updatecaseName(res.CaseName,$scope.itemToEdit);
                   $scope.loadTask();

                }

                console.log($scope.items);
            });

        };
        $scope.addTestCase=function(){
            $scope.showPopup();
        }
        $scope.editRow=function(item,row){
            $scope.iseditDone=true;
            $scope.itemToEdit = row
            //  alert($scope.data.testcase)
            $scope.showPopup();
           $scope.item.CaseName= item.CaseName;

        }

        $scope.deleterow=function(item,row){

            $scope.items.splice(row, 1);
        }


})
```

Answer (score 0):

just Replace This:

```js
 sqlservice.getAllCases().then(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   $scope.items = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
     $scope.items.push(data[i]);
   console.log($scope.items);
 })
```

you have to empty the  $scope.items = [];